# vanishing of higher homotopy sheaves of cotangent complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-scheme and suppose that there is an isomorphism (in the derived category of qc-sheaves on $X$) between the cotangent complex, $\mathbb{L}_{X}$, and its 0th homotopy sheaf, the cotangent sheaf $\Omega_{X}$. What can we say about $X$?

Such an isomorphism exists if $X$ is a reduced local complete intersection inside a smooth scheme. Under a finite type hypothesis is the converse true?

Comment: Doesn't this condition hold in general whenever $X$ is smooth over the base?

Comment: sure, but it holds for plenty of singular things too and is more interesting in such cases. eg it holds for the cone on a smooth proj variety

Comment: 1. Why is it true for the cone? Wouldn't that contradict the converse statement you want? 2. Why "homotopy" and not "(co)homology"? 3. It is known that for $X/S$ locally of finite presentation, being lci is equivalent to $\mathcal{H}^i(L_{X/S})=0$ for $i<-1$ (Avramov). In this case if $X$ is a ci in a smooth $Y/S$ with ideal sheaf $I$, we have $L_{X/S} = [I/I^2\to \Omega_{Y/S}\otimes \mathcal{O}_X]$ (in degrees $-1$ and $0$), and you are left with checking when this map is injective.

Comment: I don't see why it would contradict it. It's implicit somewhere in eisenbud, I'll look it up later. For now I'll say it's instructive just to work out an example like xy-z^2 to see what I mean

Comment: As for homotopy vs cohom sorry it's just the school I come from

Comment: Well, $xy-z^2=0$ is a hypersurface, so a complete intersection. Now take some random smooth subvariety of $\mathbf{P}^N$, then most likely it will not be a (global) complete intersection, and the cone won't be a (local) complete intersection. What then?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry I absolutely meant "hypersurface" - dunno what I was thinking